# Change the name of 'terraform.tfstate.d' in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create env specific deployment using workspace in terraform. It is working as expected like creating env specific states. It looks like

```
terraform.tfstate.d
   |
   ---- DEV
          |
          -----terraform.tfstate
   |
   ---- STAG
          |
          -----terraform.tfstate
```

How to change the name of **terraform.tfstate.d** to env

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is an implementation detail and not something you should really be worried about.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR because it look weird. I thought of giving a meaningful name like ENV

Answer (score 4):

@skull it is possible to provide a different name by using "local" backend:

```
terraform {
  backend "local" {
    path = "relative/path/to/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/local.html

For reference:

https://shinglyu.com/web/2019/04/06/switching-between-multiple-local-backend-in-terraform.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/index.html

https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/how-to-terraform-locking-state-in-s3-2dc9a5665cb6